# Using Aggregate to sum rows SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Ok i'm sorry about the vague Title cos I don't know how to put this. 
this is my problem.

```
CREATE TABLE dwd_temp (con VARCHAR2(10),line_no VARCHAR2(10),wgt NUMBER,pallet     VARCHAR2(10));
insert INTO  dwd_temp VALUES('a','1',10,NULL);
insert INTO  dwd_temp VALUES('b','1',11,'x');
insert INTO  dwd_temp VALUES('b','2',12,'x');
insert INTO  dwd_temp VALUES('b','3',13,'y');
```

now my requirement is to 'replace' the lines that have the same "pallet"
that is at the end i need a query to have one line that reads
b,1,23,x instead of the two lines with the pallet as 'x'.
so my result should be

```
 a           1          10           null
 b           1          23            x
 b           3          13            y
```

Comment: in you result you have a,c in 4 column which are not present in source data. Also I don't understand why there is 15 in result in 3 column and last row.

Comment: sorry about that - i used a different example by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select con, min(line_no), sum(wgt), pallet
from dwd_temp 
group by con, pallet
```

Comment: this will not work because you group by line_no (1 and 2) but there is only 1 in preferred result.

Answer (score 1):

VARCHAR2 suggest that you are using Oracle db.

```
select 
  con, min(line_no), sum(wgt), pallet
from dwd_temp
group by pallet, con;
```

or

```
select 
  min(con), min(line_no), sum(wgt), pallet
from dwd_temp
group by pallet;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fef78/3)

Answer will depend on what grouping do you want.

Comment: thanks for the answer! yes I'm using oracle but i need to run the query on SQLSERVER - the pc im working on at the moment has Oracle installed so i was using it.

Comment: @PaulusNijmaan both answers should work on SQLServer. you should avoid having two different RDMS environments when developing. This will prevent many problems in future.